# Application Installation failed error INSTALL_CANCELLED_BY_USER coming in android

Tags: android, android-studio

Application Installation failed error INSTALL_CANCELLED_BY_USER coming after applcation run on android studio via usb in any andoid phone?
[error coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OWJR.png)

error image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OWJR.png

Comment: Do you have the permissions to install it?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is already installed then uninstall it from your phone and try again.

Then try this:

TURN OFF & ON "Developer options".

ENABLE "USB DEBUGGING" again.

CLICK on "REVOKE USB DEBUGGING AUTHORIZATIONS".

Then try to run again and accept the popped-up msg to verify the access.

If that doesn't help,
Try this:

Step 1: Go to "Setting" → "Developer options" in System.

Step 2: TURN ON "Verify apps over USB" in Debugging section.

Step 3: Try "Run app" in Android Studio again!

If none of these techniques helped, you may check your phone usb driver.

Answer (score 0):

I am using redme note3 as I update os to 6.0 Marshmellow,this error came frequently when I tried to install apk in my phone using android studio.
One problem occurs that i couldnt change install app using usb option in developer menu .So One solution I got for Xiomi phone 
1.login in into your mi cloud
2.Then on install app using usb option in developer menu
3.Again run android studio.
4.It works

Answer (score 0):

In your android phone go to

1. Settings
2. Developer options
3. In that, enable developer options, and then
4. Enable USB debugging and Install via USB.

That's all I had to do to run my project on a real device. And it worked for me.